# linkedin-j exception Access to people search denied

Tags: java, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

Could you help me, plese?
I have some trouble. I want to search people in LinkedIn. But i get exception:

com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: Access to people search denied. at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.createLinkedInApiC‌​lientException(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3906) at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(Base‌​LinkedInApiClient.java:3781) at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(Base‌​LinkedInApiClient.java:3725) at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.searchPeople(BaseL‌​inkedInApiClient.java:1184) at test2.TestLink.main(TestLink.java:141)

What was my mistake?

### This is piece of my code.

---

```
final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory.newInstance(linkedinKey,linkedinSecret);
final LinkedInApiClient client =  factory.createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);
People people = client.searchPeople();
```

Comment: Post the error as text in your post, not as an image.

Comment: com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.LinkedInApiClientException: Access to people search denied.
 at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.createLinkedInApiClientException(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3906)
 at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3781)
 at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.callApiMethod(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:3725)
 at com.google.code.linkedinapi.client.impl.BaseLinkedInApiClient.searchPeople(BaseLinkedInApiClient.java:1184)
 at test2.TestLink.main(TestLink

Comment: Please edit that into your post, in a code block.

Comment: Done. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For linked in people search its not sufficient to have the api and secret key. Your application has to be approved for vetted program.

See here for more details

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api